Add script to IP port on Microsoft Server 2019 as Print Server
I'm currently trying to setup fake printer on server to obtain files and store them on disc to use them in another app. I need to intercept print request from another computer when it chooses this fake printer and use Windows built in print action (ctrl + p).
Now printer is added, and is visible through network -> server computer -> printer. I can use it as printing device for example in Word document. On a server I can run PowerShell script for only monitoring port and already created print jobs. I have seen a possibility to add script in this window, but there should be also option for it and I'm thinking that should be able to intercept request at its start.
config tcp/ip port window
Have anybody else wanted to intercept printer jobs to acces files? Does Windows Server need additional roles or options to be able to do that? Maybe I should add specific driver for fake printer? I have seen HP universal print monitor port but I didn't use it. I have created TCP/IP port. Also I heard about custom print processor but its is also black magic for me.
I used console app in c# to also monitor jobs but cannot extract actual file from it. I dont think it is usefull but it showed me each print job request to printers or fake printers throught server
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winspool.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "winspool.lib")

#define MAX_PRINTER_NAME 256
#define MAX_JOB_NAME 256

void SavePrintJobData(HANDLE hPrinter, JOB_INFO_2* pJobInfo) {
    DWORD dwNeeded = 0, dwReturned = 0;
    BYTE* pJobData = NULL;

    if (!GetJob(hPrinter, pJobInfo->JobId, 2, NULL, 0, &dwNeeded)) {
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) {
            pJobData = (BYTE*)malloc(dwNeeded);
            if (pJobData) {
                if (GetJob(hPrinter, pJobInfo->JobId, 2, pJobData, dwNeeded, &dwReturned)) {
                    JOB_INFO_2* pFullJobInfo = (JOB_INFO_2*)pJobData;

                    char filename[MAX_PATH];
                    sprintf_s(filename, sizeof(filename), "C:\\PrintJobs\\%s", pFullJobInfo->pDocument);

                    FILE* file;
                    if (fopen_s(&file, filename, "wb") == 0) {
                        if (pFullJobInfo->pDatatype && strcmp(pFullJobInfo->pDatatype, "RAW") == 0) {
                            // Próba pobrania surowych danych zadania
                            DWORD cbWritten;
                            if (ReadPrinter(hPrinter, file, pFullJobInfo->Size, &cbWritten)) {
                                printf("Raw data saved to: %s\n", filename);
                            }
                            else {
                                printf("Error reading raw data.\n");
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            printf("Job isn in raw format.\n");
                        }
                        fclose(file);
                    }
                    else {
                        printf("Error open file to save.\n");
                    }
                }
                free(pJobData);
            }
        }
    }
}

void MonitorPrintJobs() {
    PRINTER_NOTIFY_INFO* pInfo = NULL;
    PRINTER_NOTIFY_OPTIONS options;
    HANDLE hChange = NULL;
    DWORD dwChange;

    PRINTER_NOTIFY_OPTIONS_TYPE types[1];
    types[0].Type = JOB_NOTIFY_TYPE;
    types[0].Reserved0 = 0;
    types[0].Reserved1 = 0;
    types[0].Reserved2 = 0;
    types[0].Count = 1;
    types[0].pFields = (PWORD)calloc(1, sizeof(WORD));
    types[0].pFields[0] = JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_DOCUMENT;

    options.Version = 2;
    options.Flags = 0;
    options.Count = 1;
    options.pTypes = types;

    HANDLE hPrinter = NULL;
    PRINTER_DEFAULTS defaults = { NULL, NULL, PRINTER_ACCESS_USE };

     if (OpenPrinter(NULL, &hPrinter, &defaults)) {
        hChange = FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification(hPrinter, PRINTER_CHANGE_ALL, 0, &options);

        if (hChange != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            while (TRUE) {
                dwChange = WaitForSingleObject(hChange, INFINITE);
                if (dwChange == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
                    DWORD dwResult;
                    if (FindNextPrinterChangeNotification(hChange, &dwResult, &options, (LPVOID*)&pInfo)) {
                        for (DWORD i = 0; i < pInfo->Count; i++) {
                            if (pInfo->aData[i].Type == JOB_NOTIFY_TYPE && pInfo->aData[i].Field == JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_DOCUMENT) {
                                JOB_INFO_2* pJobInfo = NULL;
                                DWORD cbNeeded = 0, cReturned = 0;

                                EnumJobs(hPrinter, 0, 1, 2, NULL, 0, &cbNeeded, &cReturned);
                                if (GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) {
                                    pJobInfo = (JOB_INFO_2*)malloc(cbNeeded);
                                    if (EnumJobs(hPrinter, 0, 1, 2, (LPBYTE)pJobInfo, cbNeeded, &cbNeeded, &cReturned)) {
                                        SavePrintJobData(hPrinter, pJobInfo);
                                    }
                                    free(pJobInfo);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    FindNextPrinterChangeNotification(hChange, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                }
            }
            FindClosePrinterChangeNotification(hChange);
        }
        ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
    }

    free(types[0].pFields);
}

int main() {
    MonitorPrintJobs();
    return 0;
}


The printserver will only process the raw document, it's the PCL or Postscript language transformation to the printqueue. It's why it's a driver that process the data. Most likely you can only get the filename and number of pages from the Windows API.

what if i use ghostscript with radmon for example. I can conver files to pdf but also need to automatically set output ffile directory and run some code to make changes in database. Is it posible with this tools?
